# How can I handle an event from a C# user control in a VB6 form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb6, com-interop

I have a C# user control that is exposed through COM interop and is hosted by a VB6 form. In the VB6 form, how can I detect when the user clicks the Close button in the user control, so that I can close the VB6 form?

Comment: How are you loading the .Net control within VB6? Is it a COM control?

Comment: Could you provide us with some code?

Comment: Raise an event in the C# user  control. Handle the event in the VB6 form and use me.Unload.

Comment: Have you tried posting a WM_CLOSE message to the parent window?

Comment: Look at the [Interop Forms Toolkit for C#](https://interoptoolkitcs.codeplex.com/). The project template includes examples of raising events. If the question is reopened I can post a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I presume because youre calling it in this way the vb6 form is running as a separate process?

Cant you add events to whatever the process is after youve called it to catch when it closes?

```
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += (sender, e) => {  /* do whatever you need to when it closes, i.e. remove the user control or close its parent form. */ };
```